# What's the difference between a driver program and a unit test?

Tags: java, theory

According to lots of traditional theory, "driver programs" are programs that use other class(es)/module(s)/etc that you are working on.

However, I believe this is also what a unit test class does.

Is there a technical difference between the two?

Comment: unit tests are a subset of drivers.  All unit tests are drivers, but not all drivers are unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

My take is that a driver is a piece of code used to perform a unit test. A wide range of available sources seem to agree, for example, [this page](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StandardDefinitionOfUnitTest).

Answer (score 0):

Before unit tests were common place, driver programs were used to test e.g. libraries written in C or fully integrated systems.

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/90982-what-driver-program.html

So it's pretty much an integration test.

Junit and BDD style automated tests are still relatively new. I think junit and TDD date back to the late nineties.